# Linear homomorphisms of square matrices are conjugations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I was doing some linear algebra exercises and came across the following tough problem :

> Let $M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$ denote the set of all the matrices whose entries are real numbers. Suppose $\phi:M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})\to M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$ is a nonzero linear transform (i.e. there is a matrix $A$ such that $\phi(A)\neq 0$) such that for all $A,B\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$
>   $$\phi(AB)=\phi(A)\phi(B).$$
>   Prove that there exists a invertible matrix $T\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$ such that 
>   $$\phi(A)=TAT^{-1}$$
>   for all $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbf{R})$.

This is an exercise from my textbook and I am all thumbs when I attempted to solve it .

Can someone tell me as to how should I , at least , start the problem ?

Comment: One direction should be rather trivial (Given $T\in GL(n)$ show that $A\mapsto T^{-1}AT$ satisfies the properties). A useful start might be to see that $\phi(I) = I$.

Comment: It true that $\phi(I_n)=I_n$, but how to prove this?  $\phi$  is nonzero    may be an important hint.

Comment: @Brenton That's not enough. Instead see that
$$\phi(I) \phi(B) = \phi(IB) = \phi(B)$$
For all $B\in\mathbb R^{n\times n}$, wich is the definition of multiplicative identity.

Comment: @AlexR how do we know that $\phi(B)$ is invertible for *any* $B$?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom We don't but this shows that $\phi(I)$ is the multiplicative identity on the subring $\phi(\mathbb R^{n\times n})$.

Comment: @AlexR... which is not necessarily the identity matrix

Comment: @Brenton $\phi(I_n)=\phi(I_n)^2$ is not suffice to prove $\phi(I_n)=I_n$, since projection operators also satisfy the property.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, only if $\phi$ is surjective. But that makes me think the assignment might be false. If a non-surjective map of such type exists, we can't express it in the sought form.

Comment: Do you know the classification of the linear operators that preserve rank?

Comment: @AlexR I think the fact that $\phi$ is a linear transformation has to factor in

Comment: @AlexR To prove this, I think we need $\phi(B)$ is invertible.

Comment: $\phi(I)$ is invertible otherwise $\phi(A)=\phi(A)\phi(I)$ is not invertible for any $A$ and this map would not be surjective.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Projections are linear as well... They must break something with the homomorphism part.

Comment: Any linear operator that preserves rank has the format $\phi(A)=DAC$ or $\phi(A)=DA^tC$. You can use this to solve your problem.

Comment: @XiangYu No, the definition of multiplicative identity is that $$IA = A$$ for all $A$ in your ring. If $\phi$ is surjective, the ring $\phi(\mathbb R^{n\times n})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and therefor $\phi(I_n) = I_n$ if $\phi$ is surjective. If it's not, $\phi(I)$ is only the identity on the range of $\phi$.

Comment: For those with a more advanced background who might weigh in: I think that answering this question is equivalent to classifying the Lie algebra endomorphisms of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: If I well understand we have $\phi(A^n)=[\phi(A)]^n$, so it seems that $A$ and $\phi(A)$ have the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: @EmilioNovati that's perfect! So, we note that $\phi$ takes the matrix
$$
\pmatrix{1\\&2\\&&\ddots\\&&&n}
$$
to a similar matrix, so $\phi$ takes an invertible matrix to some other invertible matrix.  It follows that $\phi(I) = I$, and so $\phi$ takes invertible matrices to invertible matrices.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I believe Emilio used that $\phi(I)=I$ to obtain the same minimal polynomial.

Comment: How do you get $\phi(I) = I$ from Emilio's comment? It only holds for $n=1,...$.

Comment: @Daniel wow, I overthought that one.

Comment: @copper.hat $I$ is the only matrix with its minimal polynomial.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: Excuse my slowness, but how do you get that the minimal polynomial of $\phi(I)$ is the same as that of $I$?

Comment: @copper.hat in retrospect, it's not immediately clear; we only have $\phi(A^n) = [\phi(A)]^n$ for $n > 0$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom: I realise that $\phi(I) = I$, but was unable to derive it from minimal polynomial considerations.

Comment: @copper.hat well assuming the minimal polynomial is preserved: the minimal polynomial of $I$ is $x - 1$.  The only matrix satisfying this polynomial is of course the identity, so that is the only matrix with this minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This kind of problems are known as *linear preserver problems* in the literature. The following is a sketch of proof that immediately comes to my mind. Certainly there are simpler ways to solve the problem (especially if one makes use of existing results on linear preserver problems), but anyway, let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$ and $E_{ij}=e_ie_j^T$.

1. Prove that $\phi$ is injective. *Hint.* Suppose the contrary that $\phi(X)=0$ for some matrix $X$ whose $(r,s)$-th entry is nonzero. Now consider $\phi(E_{ir}XE_{sj})$ for every $(i,j)$.
2. Prove that

   - $\phi$ preserves non-invertibility (*hint:* if $X$ is singular, then $XY=0$ for some nonzero $Y$),
   - $\phi$ preserves invertibility (*hint:* if $\phi(P)$ is singular for some invertible $P$, then $\phi(P)Y=0$ for some nonzero matrix $Y$; since $\phi$ is an injective linear operator over a finite dimensional vector space, $Y=\phi(B)$ for some nonzero $B$, but then ...),
   - $\phi(I)=I$.
3. This is the only interesting step in the whole proof: show that every $\phi(E_{ii})$ is a ***rank-1*** idempotent matrix. *Hint:* the rank of an idempotent matrix is equal to its trace.
4. Argue that without loss of generality, we may assume that $\phi(E_{11})=E_{11}$.
5. Show that whenever $i,j\ne1$, the first column and the first row of $\phi(E_{ij})$ are zero (*hint:* $E_{ij}E_{11}=0=E_{11}E_{ij}$). By mathematical induction/recursion, show that we may further assume that $\phi(E_{ii})=E_{ii}$ for every $i$.
6. For any off-diagonal coordinate pair $(i,j)$, show that $\phi(E_{ij})$ is a scalar multiple of $E_{ij}$ (*hint:* we have $E_{kk}E_{ij}=0$ for every $k\ne i$ and $E_{ij}E_{kk}=0$ for every $k\ne j$).
7. Hence prove that *in addition to* all the previous assumptions (i.e. $\phi(E_{ii})=E_{ii}$ and $\phi(E_{ij})$ is a scalar multiple of $E_{ij}$ for every $i,j$), we may further assume that $\phi(E_{\color{red}{1}j})=E_{\color{red}{1}j}$ for every $j$.
8. Since $\phi$ preserves invertibility and non-invertibility, prove that $\phi(E_{ij})=E_{ij}$ for every $(i,j)$.

Comment: You seem to have all the answers! +1

Comment: A key here seems to be to find a basis such that $B_{ij} B_{mn} = \delta_{jm} B_{in}$.

Comment: May I ask a qustion?How can we show that $\mathrm{rank}(\phi(E_{ii})=1$?sine we only have $\phi(E_{ii})=\phi(E_{ii}^2)=\phi(E_{ii})^2$, which implies $\phi(E_{ii})$ is a idempotent matrix.

Comment: @XiangYu Well, $\phi$ is injective and linear and $\phi(E_{ii})$ is idempotent. Therefore the rank of $\phi(E_{ii})$ is at least one. Now the sum of traces of all $\phi(E_{ii})$ is equal to $n$ because $\phi(I)=I$. So ...

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, sort of. In principle this problem is not that different from those more familiar linear algebra exercises that can be solved by manipulating those $E_{ij}$s (such as finding the center of $M_n(\mathbb R)$). This one just needs a few more steps.

Comment: @user1551: I was hoping I could find a more 'geometric' proof, possibly utilising the trace/Frobenius inner product :-). After 90 mins. (including some inadvertent nap time) I failed...

Comment: @copper.hat I believe there's a more geometric proof. Here is a sketch: $\phi$ can be extended by linearity to work on complex matrices. It can be shown that $\phi$ is a bijective linear map that preserves maximal rank-1 subspaces and hence also rank-1 matrices. Such linear operators defined on $M_n(\mathbb F)$ with an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ of characteristic 0 are known to take the form of $\phi(A)\equiv PAQ$ or $\phi(A)\equiv PA^TQ$. Using $\phi(I)$ and $\phi(AB)\equiv\phi(A)\phi(B)$, we get $Q=P^{-1}$. The proof is complete if one can show that $P$ can be taken to be real.

Comment: Yet what is being 'geometric' here (namely, $\phi$ preserves maximal rank-1 matrix subspaces) is probably not what you wanted.

Comment: @user1551: Thanks - I need to digest that, my algebra is remedial...

Answer (score 3):

Here is an alternative proof that is much less computational. It works over any field. Let $E_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ at the $(i,j)$-th entry and zeros elsewhere.

1. $\phi$ is injective and hence an automorphism. Suppose the contrary that $\phi(A)=0$ for some nonzero $A$. Since $A$ is nonzero, every square matrix $B$ can be written as a finite sum of the form $\sum_k X_kAY_k$ (that's simply because Kronecker products of the form $Y_k^T\otimes X_k$ span the set of all $n^2\times n^2$ matrices). But then we would have $\phi(B)=\sum_k\phi(X_k)\phi(A)\phi(Y_k)=0$ for every $B$, which is a contradiction because $\phi\ne0$.
2. $\phi$ preserves the rank/nullity of a matrix. As $\phi$ is an automorphism, $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ preserve the linear dependence/independence of any set of matrices. In turn,
   $$
   \frac1n\dim\{X\in M_n(\mathbb C):\,AX=0\}=\frac1n\dim\{Y\in M_n(\mathbb C):\,\phi(A)Y=0\}.
   $$
   As the two sides are the respective nullities of $A$ and $\phi(A)$, the conclusion follows. In particular, $\phi$ preserves singularity/invertibility of matrices and $\phi(I)=I$.
3. As $\phi$ is an automorphism, a polynomial $p$ annihilates a matrix $A$ if and only if it annihilates $\phi(A)$. It follows that

   - $A$ and $\phi(A)$ always have identical minimal polynomials.
   - So, if $A$ is diagonalisable, $\phi(A)$ must be diagonalisable too and the two matrices must share the same set of eigenvalues. The multiplicities of the eigenvalues must be identical too, because $A-\lambda I$ and $\phi(A)-\lambda I$ have the same rank for every scalar $\lambda$. In other words, $\phi(A)$ must be similar to $A$.
   - As $\phi$ also preserve the linear independence of any set of matrices as well as matrix rank, it must map the set of all diagonal matrices onto an $n$-dimensional subspace of commuting diagonalisable matrices. Since commuting diagonalisable matrices are simultaneously diagonalisable, we may assume that $\phi$ maps diagonal matrices to diagonal matrices.
   - So, each $\phi(E_{ii})$ is a diagonal matrix that is similar to $E_{ii}$. Hence $\phi(E_{ii})=E_{jj}$ for some $j$. As $\phi$ is injective, we may assume without loss of generality that $\phi(E_{ii})=E_{ii}$ for each $i$. Hence $\phi(D)=D$ for every diagonal matrix $D$.
4. Here comes the computational part. Let $C$ be the circulant permutation matrix whose super-diagonal as well as the bottom left entry are filled with ones. By comparing the coefficients on both sides of $\phi(D_1CD_2)=D_1\phi(C)D_2$ for arbitrary diagonal matrices $D_1$ and $D_2$, we see that $\phi(C)=DC$ for some diagonal matrix $D$. Note that $\det D=1$ because $I=\phi(C^n)=(DC)^n=\det(D)I$. Write $D=\operatorname{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_n)$. Then $DC=\tilde{D}C\tilde{D}^{-1}$ where
   $$
   \tilde{D}=\operatorname{diag}\left(\prod_{j=1}^nd_j,\ \prod_{j=2}^nd_j,\ \prod_{j=3}^nd_j,\ \ldots,\ d_n\right).
   $$
   Since every matrix $A$ can be written as $A=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D_kC^k$ for some diagonal matrices $D_0,D_1,\ldots,D_{n-1}$, we obtain
   \begin{align}
   \phi(A)
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\phi(D_k)\,\phi(C)^k\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D_k\left(\tilde{D}C\tilde{D}^{-1}\right)^k\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}D_k\tilde{D}C^k\tilde{D}^{-1}\\
   &=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\tilde{D}D_kC^k\tilde{D}^{-1}\\
   &=\tilde{D}A\tilde{D}^{-1}.
   \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since $\varphi$ is linear, it's only natural to investigate how it acts on the canonical basis of $M_n(k)$. Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with a single one for the entry $(i,j)$ and $0$'s elsewhere.  It is standard that $E_{ij}E_{kl} = \delta_{jk}E_{il}$, hence $\varphi(E_{ij})\varphi(E_{kl}) = \delta_{jk}\varphi(E_{il})$.

Let $e_k$ denote the $k$-th vector of the canonical basis of $k^n$.Note that if $\varphi(E_{ij}) = CE_{ij}C^{-1}$, then $\varphi(E_{ij})Ce_k = \delta_{jk}Ce_i$. With $j=k$, $$\varphi(E_{ij})Ce_j=Ce_i$$ which yields a construction of $C$ (fix $j$ and let $i$ vary), as follows.

Let $I$ denote the identity matrix. Since $\varphi \neq 0$, there is some $A$ such that $\varphi(A)\neq 0$, hence $\varphi(A)\varphi(I)\neq 0$, hence $\varphi(I)\neq 0$. Since $I=\sum_{k=1}^n E_{kk}$, there exists some $k$ such that $\varphi(E_{kk})\neq 0$. WLOG suppose $k=1$. 
Since $\varphi(E_{11})\neq 0$, there exists $e_1'\in \operatorname{im}\varphi(E_{11})\setminus\{0\}$. Define $e_i':=\varphi(E_{i1})(e_1')$. It's easy to check that every $e_i'$ is non-zero and that $(e_1',\ldots, e_n')$ is linearly independent, hence a basis. Define $C$ the matrix with columns $(e_1',\ldots, e_n')$. $C$ is invertible by construction. It is easily checked that for fixed $(i,j)$, the following holds: $$\forall k, \varphi(E_{ij})e_k' = CE_{ij}C^{-1}e_k'$$ thus $$\varphi(E_{ij}) = CE_{ij}C^{-1}$$

Hence by linearity, $\varphi(A) = CAC^{-1}$ for all $A$.

Comment: [Duplicate answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2758755/44121) are automatically spotted by a script and they should be avoided. If two different questions can be answered by exactly the same lines, one of such questions is probably a duplicate and it is the case to mark it as such.

Comment: How to prove $(e_1',\ldots, e_n')$ is linearly independent?