# Let $f:M_{n}(F) \to M_{n}(F)$ be a linear map such that $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$, prove there exists $T \in GL_{n}(F)$ such that $f(A)=TAT^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $F$ be a field, $f:M_{n}(F) \to M_{n}(F)$ be a linear map such that $f(AB)=f(A)f(B)$ for all $A,B \in M_{n}(F)$ and $f \not= 0$. Prove that there exists $T \in GL_{n}(F)$ such that $f(A)=TAT^{-1}$ for all $A \in M_{n}(F)$.

There is a hint for this exercise: use $E_{ij}E_{jk}=E_{ik}$ where $E_{ij}$ is the standard basis of $M_{n}(F)$, and use the following theorem

> If $f_1,f_2,...,f_m$ are linear maps from $V$ to $V$ such that $f_1+f_2+···+f_m=id_V$ and  $f_if_j=\delta_{ij}f_i$, $1≤i,j≤m$, then $V=f_1(V) \oplus f_2(V) \oplus ··· \oplus f_m(V)$.

I have no idea about how to use the above theorem. To use this theroem, the only linear maps I could think about is the  projection $A \to a_{ij}$ on $M_{n}(F)$. But it is uesless. I couldn't see any connection between this exercise and the above theorem.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Surb When $n = 1$, it's easy to prove $f$ is the identity map. But for $n > 1$, I don't konw where to start. I think prove $f(E)=E$ may be important but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Is $f_i f_j$ a different representation of $f_i \circ f_j$ ?

Comment: @P.Quinton Yes. $f_i f_j$ means $f_i \circ f_j$.

Comment: That's an exercise in linear algebra? That's interesting. I have seen this result for the first time in ring theory, as a special case of the Skolem-Noether theorem.

Comment: @Mark Yes. It's my linear algebra homework.

Comment: The ideas in the answers to this old [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1246705) may be useful.